# How can I change my code from change on refresh to change on day? Basically, How can I make a daily quote

Tags: javascript

this is the website i have so far, https://real-one.shifaul.repl.co
I tried to make quotes change after 24 hours

```
async function fetchTexts() {
  const [enRes, bnRes] = await Promise.all([
    fetch('/endata.json'),
    fetch('/bndata.json')
  ]);

  const en = await enRes.json();
  const bn = await bnRes.json();

  return [en.quotes, bn.quotes];
}

fetchTexts().then(([enQuotes, bnQuotes]) => {

  const totalQuotes = enQuotes.length;

  // Get Quote
  function getQuote(pickedIndex) {
    if (pickedIndex === undefined) pickedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalQuotes);
    
    const newImageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*6); document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${newImageIndex}.jpg)`;
    // Changes background of div
    document.querySelector("#text1").innerText = enQuotes[pickedIndex];
    document.querySelector("#text2").innerText = bnQuotes[pickedIndex];
  }

  getQuote(0); // index of quote when loaded
setInterval(function() {
  getQuote()
}, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
});
```

before it was like this before when it's

```
async function fetchTexts() {
  const [enRes, bnRes] = await Promise.all([
    fetch('/endata.json'),
    fetch('/bndata.json')
  ]);

  const en = await enRes.json();
  const bn = await bnRes.json();

  return [en.quotes, bn.quotes];
}

fetchTexts().then(([enQuotes, bnQuotes]) => {

  const totalQuotes = enQuotes.length;

  // Get Quote
  function getQuote() {
    const pickedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalQuotes);
    
    const newImageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*6); document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${newImageIndex}.jpg)`;
    // Changes background of div
    document.querySelector("#text1").innerText = enQuotes[pickedIndex];
    document.querySelector("#text2").innerText = bnQuotes[pickedIndex];
  }

  getQuote();
});
```

but I don't want it change after 24 hour, I want it change daily, after 12am.
also if possible can I am trying to add a button that will change the javascript

this is the full repl code:

- on refresh: https://replit.com/join/xedbtvda-shifaul
- on daily: https://replit.com/join/zoiuhhvv-shifaul

Comment: I can suggest you store the quote and image in the localstorage with the time you added it assuming it doesn't need security. and put a setTimeout for 1 minute to check the time compare it with today and refresh the quote when you read 12 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the Days since epoch start with

```
now = new Date();
days = Math.floor(now/1000/60/60/24);
```

Then you should modulo the days to the length of the quotes data array

```
pickedIndex  = days % totalQuotes
```

### Edit

So, instead of

```
const pickedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalQuotes);
```

use this

```
const now = new Date();
const days = Math.floor(now/1000/60/60/24);
const pickedIndex = days % totalQuotes
```

Comment: I didn't understand where do I put it?

Comment: I added to my answer